# Historical data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, storage

I have situation where we have 4 node Cassandra Cluster. We are planning to retain 1 year worth of data in the current Cassandra Cluster and move any data older than 1 year into some storage (space constraint reasons). This old historical data would not be used very frequently but would be used for overall analysis.

What are some of the recommendations of storing this historical data (looking for cost effective and efficient methods)? Are there any options available with Cassandra itself to handle historical data?